# SetInterval Javascript Function Applied to Ajax + Jquery Causes Page to Flicker on Reload?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, javascript

The function below will make an Ajax call to load data from a mySQL database:

```
    function displayAll() {                 
    clearInterval ( stopCompoundingInt ); //stop current Interval
        sendAjax('search', 'q', function(responseText){
        $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
            stopCompoundingInt = setInterval ( function(){  // start a new interval with below conditions:
                sendAjax('search', 'q', function(responseText){
                $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
                });
       }, 5000 );
     })
}
```

Here is one place where it is applied:

```
var eInput = "";
stopCompoundingInt = 0;
$('#searchbar').live('keyup',function() {
    eInput = $(this).val();
    if (eInput.length > 0) {

        clearInterval ( stopCompoundingInt );
        $('#display_all').hide();
        sendAjax('search', eInput, function(responseText){
             $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
              stopCompoundingInt = setInterval ( function(){
                     sendAjax('search', eInput, function(responseText){
                            $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
                     });
              }, 5000 );
       })
    } else {
        displayAll(); // run the above function to show all events
    }
});
```

**The function is supposed to run on an interval of 5 seconds if there is no text in the textbox with ID= "searchbar"**

Does anyone have any suggestions that will improve the performance of this function?

Many Thanks,

Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want try [jQuery .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and see [jQuery Timers plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers). I believe reusing their solution is quite good and quite simple solution.

Comment: ok thank you. I actually just decided to change the way the function executes and that worked out fine.